# How to check input values in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function checkNullSearch(e) {
    if ($('#searchInput').val() === "") {
        $('#searchInput').attr("value", "null");
    }
}
```

script.js

```
<form role="form" id="form-arya">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="panel panel-primary searchPanel">
            <div class="input col-sm-12">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchInput"
                       name="searchInput"
                       aria-describedby="Not Null"
                       placeholder="Search"
                       required>                    
            </div>
            <div class="inputAndButtons">
                <div class="standartSearch">
                    <button class="btn btn-arya btn-success" type="submit" name="ara"
                            value="standart">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true" onclick="checkNullSearch(this)"></i>
                        Search
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

xxx.html

Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't work
I want to on the input control to do. I want return "null" if input is empty value's

Comment: When "doesn't it work"? Can you provide a [MCVE]? Might you `trim()` the input first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your button code like below:-

```
<button class="btn btn-arya btn-success" type="submit" name="ara" value="standart" onclick="checkNullSearch(this)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>Search</button>
```

And use `$.trim()` in your jQuery code

```
function checkNullSearch(e) {
    if ($.trim($('#searchInput').val()) == "") {
        $('#searchInput').attr("value", "null");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for inputs whitespace characters.There may whitespace characters even though the input seems to be empty.Try to remove those whitespaces using the trim() method

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to get input value

```
function getInputValue(id) {
return document.getElementById(id).value.trim();
}
```

use

```
getInputValue("searchInput")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your way is not wrong. You are using JQuery hence if you import jquery file in your page, It will work everytime. But instead of this code

```
$('#searchInput').attr("value", "null");
```

You have to use like this.

```
$('#searchInput').val('');
```

And if you want to use javascript you can check following

```
document.getElementById("#searchInput").value
```

Answer (score 0):

before check null, you need to remove white space in input text. So you can use trim function

```js
var str = "       Hello World!        ";
alert(str.trim());
```

if the browser does not support trim function, use following way

```js
function myTrim(x) {
    return x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'');
}

function myFunction() {
    var str = myTrim("        Hello World!        ");
    alert(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
function checkNullSearch() {
   if ($(#searchInput').val().trim() == "") {
     // it's empty
   }
 }
```

Comment: Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't work. Interesting. sometimes after refresh to page  it doesn't work